# Trigger or kind just to show message

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Is there any way to create trigger or any other mechanism to show simple message/popup
if value found from database? It should not prevent to do anything, just show message if value exists.
Used database is Oracle 11g.
Sample would be a nice thing.
Thanks for your ideas,
-messenger-

Comment: . . This sounds like logging values (via triggers) and an application that pops up boxes.  I would separate the logging from the user presentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a trigger, `raise_application_error` is what you should use if you want to see the "message" anywhere, in any *tool* you use. But, it'll actually stop the execution as error will be raised.

`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` isn't a good choice as it won't be visible in e.g. Forms or Apex applications.

Therefore, you should perform that check in **front end** and display the message (as an alert or whatever your application supports).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table which is getting triggered to boolean values true or false in the event of an  update or insert.